# How to validate a required query string field using model validation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Given following API

```
public class PagedRequest
{
  [Required, Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Limit must be from 1 to 100.")]
  public int Top { get; set; }

  [Required, Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Skip must be 0 or greater.")]
  public int Skip { get; set; }
}

[Route("test")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<BarResponse> GetFoos([FromQuery] PagedRequest request)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

  // Return 200 OK with data here
}
```

Works as expected:

- test?skip=0&top=10 -> returns 200
- test?skip=0&top=0 -> returns BadRequest with error messages

Doesn't work as expected

- test?top=0, returns 200 OK, expected required field validation error for Skip field.

Notes:

- Using ASP.NET Core 3.0
- This used to work with FromUri in ASP.NET Framework 4.x, then I'ld use a non-parameterless constructor, which is no longer allowed

Comment: You could also use `[BindRequired]` instead.

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin. Using [BindRequired] makes it work without changing to nullable ints. If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @KirkLarkin is correct. Here is a link to docs to support the provided suggestion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#top-level-node-validation-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the `[Required]` attribute with the [`[BindRequired]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bindrequired-attribute) attribute, which:

> Causes model binding to add a model state error if binding cannot occur for a model's property.

```
public class PagedRequest
{
    [BindRequired, Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Limit must be from 1 to 100.")]
    public int Top { get; set; }

    [BindRequired, Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Skip must be 0 or greater.")]
    public int Skip { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you're missing the `ApiController` attribute on your Controller class. This attribute applies a couple of default conventions which are common for web APIs, but uncommon for web pages. Although honestly I can't really figure out which convention it is that makes your sample work. It probably has something to do with the model binder.

See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#apicontroller-attribute

Additionally, with the `ApiController` attribute you no longer need to check to model state yourself. If the model state is invalid, ASP.NET Core MVC will automatically return a bad request response. So you can remove this part after applying the attribute:

`if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);`